# Linking a CSS Stylesheet with an ASP.NET Custom Control

Tags: asp.net, css, custom-controls, stylesheet

I'm developing a custom control which is a composition of tables and buttons. I also have an external CSS stylesheet that defines the styles for these elements.

The Control's type is **CompositeControl**, under namespace **MyControls** and the definition of the class is in a class file **CompositeControl.cs** and the dll file generated is named **MyControls.dll**

The stylesheet is called **styles.css** and is in the same folder as CompositeControl.cs

For each control (Button, TableCell, etc.), I have specified the `CssClass` property.

When I add this control to my ASP.NET webpage and check the HTML source when run at localhost, I see all the control tags have the class attribute correctly set, but the source doesn't include the `<link>` tag which is necessary for including an external stylesheet.

Could someone tell me what else I need to do to make this work? Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

External source files are not included to the page automatically. You should register them manually within your control to your page :

```
HtmlLink cssSource = new HtmlLink();
cssSource.Href = Page.ClientScript.GetWebResourceUrl(this.GetType(), "styles.css");
cssSource.Attributes["rel"] = "stylesheet";
cssSource.Attributes["type"] = "text/css";
Page.Header.Controls.Add(cssSource);
```

Also try to use [ClientScriptManager.GetWebResourceUrl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientscriptmanager.getwebresourceurl.aspx) to get location of your embedded resource. Here is [an example](http://aspalliance.com/726_Embedding_Resources_in_ASPNET_20_Assemblies) of referencing an embedded resource.

Comment: After using GetWebResourceUrl, the stylesheet doesn't get linked.

Comment: @wacky_coder : Yeah I see now the problem, the first parameter, type parameter, should be the container of the resource. In this case your control's type.

Comment: I had already tried it before even posting here. It simply didn't work. Did I miss anything? Do I need to do anything else for this method to work?

Comment: The resource gets embedded into the DLL but the webpage can't find it.